# Nuxt 3 use different api url based on environment?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Is there a way to use different api url based on environment in Nuxt 3?

In Nuxt 2 I could use something like this in the config file:

```
const isProdEnv = process.env.DEPLOYMENT_ENV === 'production'
const testEndpoint = 'https://TESTENDPOINT'
const prodServicesEndpoint = 'https://PRODENDPOINT'
const servicesEndpoint = isProdEnv ? prodServicesEndpoint : testServicesEndpoint


export default {
  env: {
    apiBaseUrl: servicesEndpoint
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Nuxt 3 syntax you can write the same as following:

```
const isProdEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const testEndpoint = 'https://TESTENDPOINT'
const prodServicesEndpoint = 'https://PRODENDPOINT'
const servicesEndpoint = isProdEnv ? prodServicesEndpoint : testServicesEndpoint

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiBaseUrl: servicesEndpoint
    }
  },
  // ...
 })
```

Then you can access it in your code with:

```
const { public: { apiBaseUrl }} = useRuntimeConfig()
```

See the [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config) for additional info.

Comment: how the `isProdEnv` will change? like `production` or `local`?

Comment: That changes based on Nodejs. If you run `nuxi dev` is `false` and if you run `nuxi build` is `true`.

Comment: `"scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },` I have this scripts in my  package.json file and I wan to determine flag like wether it is dev or staging on my nuxt.config.ts file when I run `npm run generate`. hope you understand

Comment: `npm run dev` should return `false` and `npm run generate` should return `true`.

Comment: thanks for your revert. its fine but is there any way to handle development, staging, and production?

as currently we are getting `process.env.NODE_ENV = production` on running the `npm run build` or `npm run generate` and got the `development` when we run `npm run dev` but if I need staging is there any way to indicate this?

Comment: That is not related to Nuxt I think but is up of where you deploy. On Vercel I know you can set different variables for Production, Preview and Development.